# How to setup and run old laravel project with a newer version of php?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am currently working on rewriting a `php/laravel` based project to a javascript stack.I have never worked with `php` or `laravel` and we cannot contact the previous devs. I am having issues running the project locally.

I have installed

- `php` version `8.1.10`
- `Composer` version `2.4.2`

So I believe similar to a js based project where you need to do `npm i` I ran `composer install` in order to install all the dependencies. However I get the following stack trace. I also tried `composer update`

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ~6.5.14 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.5.14].
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - illuminate/contracts[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/contracts[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/contracts[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-cors ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-cors[v3.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.25 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.26 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.27 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.28 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.29 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.30 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.31 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.32 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.33 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.35 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.36 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.37 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.38 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.42 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.43 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.45 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.46 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.47 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.50 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - barryvdh/laravel-cors v3.0.0 requires illuminate/contracts ^6|^7|^8|^9 -> satisfiable by illuminate/contracts[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.25, v9.0.0, ..., v9.36.3].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/contracts[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.25, v9.0.0, ..., v9.36.3], laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.5.50]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/contracts and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.5.50].
```

This is my composer.json file

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0|^8.1.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^3.0.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "v2.4.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^4.12",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.11",
        "yoeunes/toastr": "^1.2",
        "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.14"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my understanding you need to backup your vendor folder (and rename it) and then run (1) composer install 
(2) composer dump-autoload
(3) php artisan cache:clear
(4) php artisan config:clear

Comment: `phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0` or `illuminate/contracts[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2` - anything unclear about this? Why not use the PHP version the other developer used?

Comment: You can't run Laravel 5 on PHP 8

Comment: I tried installing an older verison of php using `brew install php@7.2 ` however I get the following error `Error: php@7.2 has been disabled because it is deprecated upstream!`

Comment: Yeah, another error message that is self-explanatory: PHP 7.2 is too outdated to be installable over Brew